# What is the name of this apricot and yellow rose?

Tags: identification, roses

I am looking to id this rose:

[image]

*Click photo for full size*

I am no rose expert, and did a search for apricot yellow rose and there are a million of them. I could just root one, but I would like to pay my dues to whomever developed this very pleasant rose.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've found so far it could be one of these, I'm not too confident with the answer though, so I'll keep looking.

It may be (in order of likeliness):

A ["sunstruck" hybrid](http://www.themulch.com/component/plants/?view=plants&plantid=84815)

[image: Sunstruck]

- [search here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sunstruck+rose&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=C5WRUfiMArOu4AO1ioDYDQ&biw=1280&bih=645&sei=DZWRUcTsOvip4AOmkIHICw)

A ["gold medal" hybrid](http://www.themulch.com/component/plants/?view=plants&plantid=84759)

[image: A little bit staged, but it is quite similar]

- [search here](https://www.google.com/search?q=gold+medal+rose&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=g5GRUaSIFtbl4AOI2YDADw&biw=1280&bih=645&sei=hZGRUdT8OoW64AO8-YCoAw)

A ["tahitian sunset"](http://www.themulch.com/component/plants/?view=plants&plantid=86345)

[image: Tahitian Sunset]

- [search here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=_6_nhiW_-m-fL-0tbyC1Hw&pq=tahitian+sunset&cp=16&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=tahitian+sunset+rose&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46471029,d.dmg&biw=1280&bih=645&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=Q5SRUau9Mbap4APvz4Fw)

Again I'm not sure, you can search for yourself through the "search here" links to compare

Comment: close... but the main cool thing about this rose is the apricot is just on the underside of the petals.